# pandas: sorting and dropping rows from a grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

   brand  rating
0      a      81
1      a      83
2      a      60
3      a      45
4      b      73
5      b      55
6      b      90
7      c      60
8      d      70
9      e      75
10     e      80
11     e      85
```

So far, I have figured out how to group my dataframe by brand and calculate the mean and count per brand category:

```
groupeddf = df.groupby('brand', as_index=False).agg(['count', 'mean'])
```

which produces:

```
      rating           
       count       mean
brand                  
a          4  67.250000
b          3  72.666667
c          1  60.000000
d          1  70.000000
e          3  80.000000
```

Now, I would like to sort these results by the mean value and drop any brands for which there are less than three (so in this case, drop the rows for C and D).

I was trying to sort by 'mean':

```
groupeddf.sort_values('mean')
```

but, I get a KeyError:'mean'

So I looked at my columns:

```
groupeddf.columns
```

which gives:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['rating'], ['count', 'mean']],
       labels=[[0, 0], [0, 1]])
```

And, now I'm not really sure what to do. All I want to do, is:

- group my original dataframe by brand
- calculate the mean and number of
  each brand
- sort by mean in descending order
- eliminate any data where
  the count < 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `tuple` key to index the `MultiIndex` of your DataFrame:

```
s = df.groupby('brand').agg(['count', 'mean'])

s[s[('rating', 'count')] >= 3].sort_values(by=('rating', 'mean'))
```

```
      rating
       count       mean
brand
a          4  67.250000
b          3  72.666667
e          3  80.000000
```

---

If you'd like to avoid creating the `MultiIndex` in the first place, `agg` on your `Series` instead of the entire `DataFrame`:

```
s = df.groupby('brand').rating.agg(['count', 'mean'])
```

```
       count       mean
brand
a          4  67.250000
b          3  72.666667
c          1  60.000000
d          1  70.000000
e          3  80.000000
```

Now indexing is simpler:

```
s[s['count'] >= 3].sort_values(by='mean')
```

```
       count       mean
brand
a          4  67.250000
b          3  72.666667
e          3  80.000000
```